# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: The script tried to modify a property on an incomplete object

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors, fatal-error

I am getting this error when I try to place an order with WooCommerce:
[image]

I tried to deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce and tried to use a basic Wordpress theme. But it is still not fixed.

What else could I try?

Comment: A search of GitHub shows that the class causing the error comes from a plugin called woocommerce-product-customizer? Did you deactivate that one? You should contact its author for assistance, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Can you paste the acutal error code here rather than a picture? It makes it easier to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things you can try:
Increase Memory Limit: Sometimes, PHP memory limit issues can cause such errors. Try increasing the memory limit by adding define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); to your wp-config.php file.

Check WooCommerce Status: Go to WooCommerce > Status in your WordPress admin to see if there are any alerts or recommendations.